# Parsing numbers from HTML strings in Java

Tags: java

When parsing HTML, every time i have a '>' `char`, I need to check if there is a number after it.  The number can be of 1, 2 or 3 digits.

The code seems OK, but I always get a `StringIndexOutOfBoundException`.

Code:

```
while (matches < 19) 
    {
        more  = dataInHtml.indexOf(">",index);
        nextOne = dataInHtml.charAt(more + 1);
        nextTwo = dataInHtml.charAt(more + 2);
        nextThree = dataInHtml.charAt(more + 3);

        if (Character.isDigit(nextOne))  digitOne = true;
        if (Character.isDigit(nextTwo))  digitTwo = true;       
        if (Character.isDigit(nextThree))  digitThree = true;

        if (digitThree)
        {
            data[matches] = dataInHtml.substring(more + 1, 3);
            matches++;
            digitThree = false;
            digitTwo = false;
            digitOne = false;
            index = more + 3;
            itWasADigit = true;
        }

        if (digitTwo)
        {
            data[matches] = dataInHtml.substring(more + 1, 2);
            matches++;
            digitTwo = false;
            digitOne = false;
            index = more + 2;
            itWasADigit = true;
        }           

        if (digitOne)
        {
            data[matches] = dataInHtml.substring(more + 1, 1);
            matches++;
            digitOne = false;
            index = more + 1;
            itWasADigit = true;
        }           

        if (!(itWasADigit))    
        {
            index = more + 1;
            itWasADigit = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Convert characters to ASCII and compare values

Comment: Which line is doing a StringIndexOutOfBoundException ?

Comment: data[matches] = dataInHtml.substring(more + 1, 2);

Comment: If it is a well formed HTML (like xml) you can try using a SAX parser to extract the tokens and then parse it into integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass the string "string >12" to this look what it will do:

```
more  = dataInHtml.indexOf(">",index);
  nextOne = dataInHtml.charAt(more + 1); <-- get the 1
  nextTwo = dataInHtml.charAt(more + 2); <-- Get the 2
  nextThree = dataInHtml.charAt(more + 3); <-- Try to access outside of the string as more+3 is greater than the highest index in the string, so it crashes out
```

Hence you see the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Use something like this

```
if(dataInHtml.length() > more+3)
```

To check that the length of the string is big enough before trying to access that character.

If you are trying to read numbers from a HTML document this probably isnt the ideal approach to take. You should look into parseing it with a parser if possible.

http://jsoup.org/ looks promising.

Comment: >12<...   >1<...>  i have an HTML file like that

Comment: it will break because of the last `>`. After seeing it will try to access the string index that is too large